# How to Validate Network Addresses Against Netmask (CIDR) in Laravel?

Tags: laravel

I am currently working on a project where users can enter network addresses along with their corresponding netmask (CIDR notation) using Laravel. To ensure data integrity, I need to implement a validation mechanism that checks whether the entered network address is valid with respect to the provided netmask.

For example, if a user enters a network address of "192.168.1.100" and a netmask of "/25" `(255.255.255.128)`, the validation should pass as this is a valid network address within the given netmask. However, if the user enters a network address of "192.168.1.130" with the same netmask, the validation should fail as it falls outside the valid range.

Could someone please guide me on how to achieve this network address validation in Laravel? Specifically, I would like to know:

What would be the best approach to extract the network address and netmask from the input string in CIDR notation (e.g., "192.168.1.100/25")?

How can I calculate the valid network range for a given netmask (e.g., "/25" or "255.255.255.128")?

What is the most efficient way to validate the entered network address against the calculated valid network range and trigger the error message "Invalid network address for that netmask" when appropriate?

Any code examples or Laravel-specific techniques would be highly appreciated.

Comment: This question is too broad - there are many possible ways to do this, and you're doing to get lots of opinion-based answers. That said, if you happen to be storing your data in a PostgreSQL database, I suggest the [`inet << inet` operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/functions-net.html) - that's how I do something similar to what you are asking in my own Laravel applications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

long2ip — Converts a long integer address into a string in (IPv4) Internet standard dotted format (Reffer :https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.long2ip.php)

```php
$input = "192.168.1.100/25";  (/25=> IPs in Range 128 : Mask Bits 25 )
list($networkAddress, $cidr) = explode('/', $input);
```

```php
$subnetMaskLong = -1 << (32 - $cidr);
$networkAddressLong = ip2long($networkAddress);
$validRangeStart = long2ip($networkAddressLong & $subnetMaskLong);
$validRangeEnd = long2ip($networkAddressLong | (~$subnetMaskLong & 0xFFFFFFFF));
```

```php
$userEnteredIP = "192.168.1.130";
$userEnteredIPLong = ip2long($userEnteredIP);

if (ip2long($validRangeStart) <= $userEnteredIPLong && $userEnteredIPLong <= ip2long($validRangeEnd)) {
    // Your Code Here
} else {
    // Show an error message to the user
}
```

**in laravel** you can integrate this validation logic into a custom validation rule

```
php artisan make:rule <yourRuleName>
```

after you can use the custom validation rule in your controller or form request